# Show that any abelian subgroup of $D_n$ is cyclic when n is odd

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to prove that any abelian subgroup of $D_n$ is cyclic when $n$ is odd. Can someone please give me a hint how to prove this? I know that if $n$ is odd, then the centre of $D_n$ is $Z(D_n)=[e]$. And the centre of the group is a subgroup. Is this subgroup cyclic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\{e\}$ is cyclic; it is generated by $e$. However, looking at the center of the group for this problem is maybe not a very useful thing to do, as a subgroup can be abelian without being contained in the center of the whole group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Do a proof by contradiction. Suppose there is an abelian subgroup $H$ of $D_n$ which is not cyclic. Note that this means $H$ must contain some element of the form $sr^k$ for some $0<k<n$ and as it is not cyclic, it must contain another element of the form $sr^j$ or $s$ or $r^i$. Show that each of these does not commute with $sr^k$, hence the subgroup cannot have been abelian, a contradiction.